# how to get() this model that belongs to userprofile.team

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, postgresql, django-models

I'm struggling getting this view to work. In the code I have included a comment that indicated where the issue is. Basically I can not for the life of me get the TeamsWeeklyMasterSchedule object that relates to the EmployeeProfile.team

**Models**

```
class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)

    def __str__(self):
        """Return a string representation of the model."""
        return self.name


class TeamsWeeklyMasterSchedule(models.Model):
    """Hours Available For That Day"""
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class EmloyeeProfile(models.Model):
    owner = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE, )
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
```

**View**

```
@login_required
def employee(request):
    """The home page"""
    profile = EmployeeProfile.objects.filter(owner=request.user)

    # I Cannot make this get() work!
    teams_weekly_master_schedule = TeamsWeeklyMasterSchedule.objects.get()

    context = {
        'profile': profile,                                                                                    
        'teams_weekly_master_schedule': teams_weekly_master_schedule,

    }
    return render(request, 'portal/employee.html', context)
```

**What I've Tried**

```
teams_weekly_master_schedule = TeamsWeeklyMasterSchedule.objects.get(team=profile.team)

teams_weekly_master_schedule = TeamsWeeklyMasterSchedule.objects.get(team=request.user.team)
```

Comment: add the error message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to replicate the problem and I solved it with this:

```
def employee(request):
"""The home page"""
profile = EmployeeProfile.objects.get(owner=request.user)

teams_weekly_master_schedule = TeamsWeeklyMasterSchedule.objects.get(team = profile.team)

context = {
    'profile': profile,
    'teams_weekly_master_schedule': teams_weekly_master_schedule,

}
return render(request, 'test.html', context)
```

The first problem was that on line 3, you used filter to retrieve one EmployeeProfile object. Using filter returns a queryset, which can't be accessed as an object.

When you use GET, you can use profile.team which returns the team you want.

Comment: hmm getting an error: type error 'EmployeeProfile' object is not iterable

Comment: Nevermind! I was iterating over it in the template lol that's why the error came up! Thank you so much gorgeous!

Comment: Are you trying to iterate through an EmployeeProfile object? You shouldn't need to do that if there is only one object.